# apply a function to np.ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, lambda

I have one numpy array, for instance a (a.shape = (2,20,50,50)). I would like to apply a function over its second axes.

My function is the difference between each elements only along the second axis, i.e.

```
res = a[:,i+1,:,:] - a[:,i,:,:] for i in range(20)
```

I have already tried it with lambda function, but the output is a list. I would like to have the result with the same shape as a. That means I want to have res.shape = (2,20,50,50).

I do appreciate that if someone guide me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please share more code. Perhaps a small example that I can rerun and try out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to apply a function. Just subtract them directly.

```
res = a[:,1:,:,:]-a[:,0:-1,:,:]
```

Moreover, you won't get (2,20,50,50) ndarray but (2,19,50,50).

Comment: [`np.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) might be clearer, depending on whether you find it more mental effort to remember what `diff` does or interpret the slicing.

Comment: `np.diff` does exactly this slicing.  But being able to do it yourself 'from-scratch' is, in the long run, more useful than remembering that there is a `diff` wrapper.